# Quotient of quasi-isomorphic nonpositively graded cdga's

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra

I'm looking for a theorem about quotient of quasi-isomorphic cdga's:

Let $A, B$ be two cdga's (commutative differential $\mathbb Z$-graded algebra) concentrated in nonpositive degree, and $\mathfrak m \subset A, \mathfrak n \subset B$ be maximal ideals which are closed under differentials. Suppose $\phi: A \to B$ is a quasi-isomorphism of cdga's and $\phi(\mathfrak m) \subset \mathfrak n$. Is the induced map $\phi: A/ \mathfrak m^2 \to B/\mathfrak n^2$ still a quasi-isomorphism?

More assumptions on $A,B, \mathfrak m, \mathfrak n$ might be needed. Any theorems of this type would be helpful.

Comment: over what commutative ring or field are you working? that might help a lot.

Comment: @Enkidu just  real numbers